# Slider who to store integers

Tags: c#, wpf, numbers, slider

I have this WPF slider:

```
<Slider Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" TickPlacement="BottomRight" AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" Minimum="10" Maximum="110" Value="{Binding Path=Zoom, Mode=TwoWay}" Ticks="100"/>
```

and my c# code behind

```
public object Zoom
{
    get { return _zoom.ToString() }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            string zoom = value.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
            if (zoom.EndsWith(" %"))
            {
                _zoom= System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Convert.ToInt64(zoom));
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentZoom");
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            //TODO: =)
        }
    }
}
```

how is it possible that only integers can be stored in _zoom? I don't need a decimal number.

for example:

zoom is "13,99999"

_zoom should be 13 (int)

```
_zoom= System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Convert.ToInt64(zoom));
```

so i get this error:

> Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

whats wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with culture. Depending on the setting of your computer, `Convert` might expect a decimal point or a decimal comma.

Comment: why do you convert zoom to an int64, then convert that to an int32? :S why not straight into an int32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_zoom = (int)Math.Round(System.Convert.ToDouble(zoom));
```

Comment: have a look at the Math.Round method. It has an overload for the Midpoint-Rounding. Default is ToEven (eg. if you have 2.5 it will round down to 2.0. but if you have 3.5 it will round up to 4.0). With Away from zero it will always round up to the next number [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This will return the Decimal value to the LEFT of the dot/decimal.

> Calculates the integral part of a specified decimal number.

```
 Math.Truncate(zoom)
```

[More Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf.aspx)

Comment: `_zoom = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(System.Convert.ToDecimal(zoom)));` say also `Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.`

Comment: try : _zoom = Math.Truncate(zoom);